# How can i show an inputdialogbox in blackberry where it asks for Username and Password before my application is opened

Tags: blackberry

My requirement is to create a Blackberry Application Where it needs Authentication to open. Right now I created an Simple Blackberry Application Which can be opened by anyone. But I need to put a Dialogbox where it asks for username and Password. Once the credentials are valid then only the app should load. For the time being i need a dialgbox when the my app is clicked. Validation of the credentials can be done at later point of time.

Comment: can you explain why you want to ask for username and password **before** your app opens?  why can't that just be the first thing it does, and if the correct username/password are not entered, the app just doesn't let you go any farther?  otherwise, you're talking about having two apps, one just to prompt for credentials.

Comment: My app needs an Authentication to open, thats the reason i want a dialog box where user can enter his credentials and can be verified using HTTP request.If the credentials are valid only the app should open else it shouldn't open.

Comment: Ok, I edited your question based on your comments, since the original wording was a little confusing.  Just to be clear, the app *"opens"* when the user taps its home screen icon.  You want to ask for username and password **after** it opens, but don't want to continue if the username/password are not correctly entered.

Comment: yes exactly you are right, sorry for the confusion i had made.Please provide me a solution..